# Next.js 14 app dir, Fetch API cause error when optional arguments set

Tags: javascript, docker, next.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux, next.js14

I can run and get responses from these lines correctly. (in app/item/page.tsx):

```
export default async function Page() {
    const res = await fetch('http://www.testdomain.test:8000/testapi/items/');
    items = await res.json();
    console.log(items);
}
```

But when adding an optional argument to fetch, like 'method':

```
export default async function Page() {
    const res = await fetch('http://www.testdomain.test:8000/testapi/items/', {
                method: 'GET'
        });
    items = await res.json();
    console.log(items);
}
```

I get the below error:

```
Internal error: TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16)
at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
errno: -111,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 8000
}
⨯ Internal error: TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Environment settings:
1- Ubuntu 22 on windows 11 WSL
2- Both frontend and backend API run in local Docker
3- Backend is in 8000 port
4- Frontend is in 3000 port
5- There are

```
127.0.0.1 testdomain.test
127.0.0.1 www.testdomain.test
```

lines in Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file

I have searched for two days on the internet and tested all solutions, but it doesn't work.
Please help me.

Comment: Probably unrelated but your second code example has an error. You open 2 `{` but close 3. I guess you can open the URL in your browser and get a json back?

Comment: @grekier Thanks for your comment. It was a typo in the question and I corrected it in my question.

Comment: @grekier Yes, I can log the result in the browser console and also see the response in my browser for the first code. I get error for second code with the 'method' optional argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.
When you use the docker as your frontend and backend apps, you should use this type of URL in your fetch request:

```
http://[your conatainer name]:[your container port]/testapi/items/
```

Because in the docker concept, the localhost or any domain assigned to the localhost isn’t your machine; this localhost is your docker, and you can’t use it directly.
I sent the correct code and solution below to help others:

```
export default async function Page() {
    const res = await fetch('http://[your conatainer name]:[your container port]/testapi/items/', {
                method: 'GET'
        });
    items = await res.json();
    console.log(items);
}
```